# Get random top 3 record from database : php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a random image banner which fetches the image data from a MySQL database.
And I only want to fetch the latest three records, randomly.

How can I fetch the the 3 most recent records, in a random order?

I am the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM bottom_advt WHERE bottom_advt_page_name='News' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 4):

You said 3 records. So try:

```
SELECT * FROM bottom_advt WHERE bottom_advt_page_name='News' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
```

Comment: I want show only one image at a time ... but play top three latest records from databse randomly

Answer (score 1):

You're limiting your results to one with `LIMIT 1`. Change it to `LIMIT 3` to get three results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want one of the last three records:

```
SELECT * FROM bottom_advt WHERE bottom_advt_page_name='News' AND id+3>last_insert_id() ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM bottom_advt
WHERE ID IN (SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id
  FROM bottom_advt
  WHERE bottom_advt_page_name='News'
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 3) last)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Subquery will return the last 3 id that have `bottom_advt_page_name='News'`, and the outer query will randomly select one of those.

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b843f/1).